# NullPointerException when trying to access JavaFX button

Tags: javafx

I'm getting a NullPointerException when  trying to access a Button from within initialize() method.

I have marked the line below which causes the exception.

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    public Button connect;

    public MyController() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Layouts/ClientLayout.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 460, 470));
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        connect.setOnAction(e -> { // this line causes the nullpointerexception
            connect.setDisable(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure ClientLayout.fxml have fx:id for a button with connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize your button. Check your FXML. It should contain the correct fx:id:

```
<Button fx:id="connect" graphicTextGap="2.0" layoutX="716.0" layoutY="274.0" mnemonicParsing="false">
```

You should also define what do to on action with the addition of an onAction method in your FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="connect" graphicTextGap="2.0" layoutX="716.0" layoutY="274.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleConnectButtonAction">
```

and in your controller instead of putting it in the initialize method:

```
@FXML
private void handleConnectButtonAction(ActionEvent event){
    connect.setDisable(true);           
}
```